# Problem when using md5 to encrypt passwords before saving to databsae

Tags: php, mysql, session, input, md5

I have been implementing 'md5' to provide basic security to the passwords when they are saved on the database.

When I test the code, and enter in the correct password that is saved on the database and two new matching passwords, the program outputs that the 'old passwords do not match'.

I have read through the code to see if there are any syntax errors, however I cannot spot any, so I do not know what is causing the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="passwordChangeCSS.css">

</html>

<?php

session_start();

$user=$_SESSION['firstName'];

if($user)
{
    //if user is logged in
    //self submitting form

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //begin to change password
        //check fields

        $oldPassword=$_POST['oldPassword'];
        $newPassword=$_POST['newPassword'];
        $RepNewPassword=$_POST['RepNewPassword'];

        //check password against db

        $connectDB = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect");  //proving the database connection details and saving it as a variable
        mysqli_select_db($connectDB, "registration"); //table name
        $PassQuery=mysqli_query($connectDB, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE firstName='$user'") or die ("query didnt work"); //sql query to select the password relevant to the current user

        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($PassQuery); //creates array

        $oldPasswordInDB=$row['password']; //saves the users current password as a variable

        //checks old passwords

        $oldPasswordEncrypt=md5($oldPassword);

        if (($oldPasswordEncrypt) == ($oldPasswordInDB)){ 

            //check two new passwords
            if($newPassword==$RepNewPassword)
            {
                //if passwords match, success
                //change passwords in DB

                //update table, change password to new password
                $encryptNewPassword=md5($newPassword);

                $queryChange=mysqli_query($connectDB, "UPDATE users SET password='$encryptNewPassword' WHERE firstName='$user'");

                session_destroy();  //logs user out as they must log back in as they have created a new password

                die("your password has been successfully changed. You will now need to log back in. <a href ='logIn.php'>Return</a> to the Log In page");

            }
            else{
                die ("New passwords do not match."); // if the users new passwords dont match eachother, system dies and the user has to re-enter their passwords
            }

        }
        else{
            die ("Old password do not match"); //if the users old password that they input doesnt match the one on database, system dies and user has to re-enter their passwords
        }

    }
    else{


    //form for password change
    echo"

    <form class='passwordChange' action='' method='POST'>    

    <h1>Password Change</h1>

    Old Password: <input required type='text' name='oldPassword' placeholder='Enter your old password' ><p>
    New Password: <input required type='password' name ='newPassword' placeholder='Enter a new password' ><br/>
    Repeat new Password: <input required type='password' name ='RepNewPassword' placeholder='Re-enter your new password' ><p>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value= 'Change password'>



    </form>
    ";
}
}else{
    die("you must be logged in to change you password"); //user must be logged in to change password as their password is linked to their account
}
?>
```

Comment: You should call this a blessing in disguise. MD5 is no longer safe to store passwords with. Use `password_hash()` instead and prepared statements.

Comment: The simplest likely explanation is that you mistyped the old password either when you saved it in the database, or when you entered it as the old password in your test. I suggest you start over, set a new password in the database, and test again. Keep the test password simple.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to debug this is to add this in your script just before 
"if(($oldPasswordEncrypt) == ($oldPasswordInDB)){ "
and see if the outputs are what youre expecting them to be.

```
    echo $oldPassword . "<br/>";
    echo $newPassword . "<br/>";
    echo $RepNewPassword . "<br/>";
    echo $oldPasswordEncrypt . "<br/>";
    echo $oldPasswordInDB . "<br/>";
```

Be aware of any white space characters aswell, tabs, new lines, etc

As a side not, you shouldn't be using MD5 to save passwords.

Instead, you should use

```
$originalpassword = password_hash("password-goes-here", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then when you need to verify the password use

```
if (password_verify("password-when-trying-to-login", $originalpassword)) {
    echo "Password is valid!";
} else {
    echo "Invalid password.";
}
```